# Resolve a dependency issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following dependency issue:

```
   Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    active_support depends on
      activesupport (= 3.0.0)

    activerecord (= 3.0.6) depends on
      activesupport (3.0.6)
```

I need both active_support and activerecord. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried just using the latest version? Usually it seems like the versions imply "at least"?

Answer (score 2):

Check the versions of the stuff in your Gemfile. It sounds like active_support has been locked at 3.0.0 manually for some reason. Either it was done directly, or some of your other gems has a "hard" dependency on ActiveSupport 3.0.0

The first case is easy to fix, just use ActiveSupport 3.0.6 instead. The second can be probably be fixed by finding out which gem is the problem and updating it.

Comment: I had this same issue and ended up having to just update to activerecord and activesupport by hand